# Interior/boundary of unit diagonal

Tags: general-topology

Trying to wrap my head around interiors and boundaries of subsets. I'm attempting to find the interiors and boundaries of the open and closed unit diagonals w.r.t the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The open unit diagonal would be defined as something like:

A={(x,x)$\in\mathbb{R}^2$| 0 < x < 1}

Would the interior just be empty and the boundary be the entire set?
And for the closed, the boundary would be [0,1] and the interior would (0,1)?

Comment: Almost.  The interior of the closed one is still empty.

Comment: Thanks @JoeJohnson126.  Why would the boundary of the closed one be empty? Is it specific to the product topology?

Comment: I didn't say the boundary would be empty, only its interior.

Comment: sorry it was a typo, I meant interior...

Comment: The interior of a subset is the largest open set contained within it.  Open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are unions of open discs.  If the diagonal had a nonempty interior, it would have to contain at least one open disc.